# IIS services responces with strange characters

Tags: iis

I'm getting a problem on every web service response on my IIS. The output of every Web Service comes with strange characters (see image below). I tried to copy the WS to another machine and it works perfectly. Must be something on my machine/IIS configuration. Does anyone have an idea of what can be the problem?

Services responses all like this:

[image: Services responses]

```
**REQUEST HEADER:**
POST /ERESULTS/Glintths.Shell/Authentication/GetDbDate HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://localhost
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Referer: http://localhost/ERESULTS/Glintths.Shell/Authentication/Login
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pt-PT,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: USERUTC=+00:00; MvcLocalization.CurrentUICulture=pt-PT; ASP.NET_SessionId=xv0lx3akeb3dn23noummczhh

**RESPONSE HEADER:**
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: MvcLocalization.CurrentUICulture=pt-PT; expires=Sat, 07-Nov-2020 18:03:14 GMT; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 07 Nov 2019 18:03:34 GMT
Content-Length: 81920
```

Comment: Can you share your web.confg?

Comment: I think you have a character set problem. For example, if your web-service is issuing 16-bit Unicode and the web-page does not define the character set and so defaults to UTF-8. Please share one such web-page with its headers and contents.

Comment: Added header information.